# What rules would you use to validate an Australian Phone Number?

Tags: validation, phone-number

What can I do to comprehensively validate an Australian Phone Number?  I need this for an application I'm writing. You can assume it is dialed from within Australia.  I want to use a white-list approach.

Here are my rules so far (after removing any whitespace):-

1. Starts with 13 and is 6 digits long
2. Starts with 1300 and is 10 digits long
3. Starts with 0 (but not 0011 as this is international dialing) and is 10 digits long
4. Starts with +61 followed by 9 digits
5. Starts with (0_) followed by 8 digits (where _ is 1-9)

Is there anything I have missed?

Area codes are required as we may be sending a fax from our fax server in one state when the user is in a different state.

(I'm not asking how to make a regexp out of the above rules, but if those rules are correct).

See also:
[UK Phone Numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32401/validate-a-uk-phone-number)
[US Phone Numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175488/us-phone-number-verification)

Comment: If you're not asking about how to program this (regex or otherwise, this seems fairly off-topic for this site)

Comment: This wikipedia page may help: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%2B61](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%2B61)

Comment: There, fixed that for you. :-)

Comment: From a usability angle, be generous in allowing odd other characters. Why bother requiring balanced parens? If someone mistypes a single paren without closing, who cares! Also consider people using dashes or periods to separate number groups.

Comment: @Andy Dent: I need to actually use this number to send a fax (from a fax server as a background job).  So, I want to make sure as much as possible that the number entered is good.

Answer (score 10):

I did a similar thing a while ago.  The Wikipedia page that unthinkableMayhem mentioned was a great starting point.

As of a year ago, my rules looked something like:

```
02[3-9]\d{7}  NSW/ACT
03[4-9]\d{7}  VIC/TAS
07[3-9]\d{7}  QLD
08\d{8}       SA/NT/WA

04[\d]{8}     Moblies  04x[123] = Optus,  04x[456] = Voda, 04x[0789] = Telstra

0500[\d]{6}   Find me anywhere server
0550[\d]{6}   VoIP
059[\d]{7}    Enum

13[\d]{4}     Local rate
1300[\d]{6}   Local rate

1800[\d]{6}   Free call

0198[\d]{2}   Data networks (local call anyway I think)
0198[\d]{6}

190[\d]{7}    Premium rate
```

Comment: Yeah, I like this better than mine.  It looks pretty complete.

Note however that not all first digits are vlid for each area code - in SA/NT/WA the valid first numbers are 8,9, and a few others.

And I assume 0055 numbers have been completely replaced?

Comment: With mobile number portability you can't assume the carrier based on a mobile number (04[\d]{8)).

Answer (score 2):

Building on some previous answers (and I'll use Regexs as it is neater):

1. Remove any spaces or matched ( ) pairs
2. If one of the following matches, then return the number:

   1. 1[38][0-9]{4}
   2. 1300[0-9]{6}
   3. ([(0),(+61)][23478]){0,1}[1-9][0-9]{7}

Note that the area code values that are valid are [23478].  I've also assumed that 1800 numbers still exist.  I think there might be 1900 numbers as well.

Also, 000 and 112 are valid emergency numbers: depending upon your specific use case, you may want to explicitly allow or deny these numbers. If you were storing 'This is my phone number', then you'd probably want te disallow emergency numbers, but for something like a dialling plan, you'd want to allow them.

Comment: 000 is a valid number (emergency services)

Comment: Dale: good point, but is not a valid number for 'This is my phone number'.

Comment: It is if you are the triple-0 service :-). I can think of a number of applications is WHS where the emegency services number may need to be displayed - it could be hard coded but ...

Answer (score 1):

0011 is not the only international access code. For example, calling overseas by fax you should use 0015 - it avoids the voice clipping effect of compression, which is not good for fax (or data, if you happen to be using a modem). My office phone database has 0015 prefixes on some international fax numbers.  There are other special purpose international dialling codes as well.

And I still see mobile phone numbers written as (0411) 123 456

Answer (score 1):

For a definitive list, try https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber

> Google's common Java, C++ and JavaScript library for parsing, formatting, storing and validating international phone numbers. The Java version is optimized for running on smartphones, and is used by the Android framework since 4.0 (Ice Cream Sandwich).

You can test it here: https://rawgit.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber/master/javascript/i18n/phonenumbers/demo-compiled.html

This was way overkill for my little job, and I generalised my test, but that library will allow you test you rules :)

Comment: This is an old question I'd forgotten about, but we are using libphonenumber now

Comment: sweet :) thought it was worth mentioning!

Answer (score 0):

I'd be tempted to remove the parentheses as well. I still see phone numbers written like "(0212) 34 5678" every once in a while.

Are there still 008 numbers in use? How about 1800? I think that's a valid prefix similar to 1300 nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you are after:

http://www.comlaw.gov.au/comlaw%5Cmanagement.nsf/lookupindexpagesbyid/IP200506356?OpenDocument

Telecommunications Numbering Plan 1997
Establishes a framework for the numbering of carriage services and for the use of numbers in connection with the supply of carriage services, specifies the numbers for use in connection with the supply of carriage services, and establishes a framework for the allocation and portability of numbers.

It's a brief 261 page document that contains all you need to know :)