# PHP phone number validation

Tags: php, validation

I am trying to display error messages to user if they entered a wrong uk phone number format or not a number, but the error messages not working.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="phone" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $phone;?>" placeholder="Mobile Number "> 


<span class="error"><?php echo $phoneErr;?></span>
```

**PHP**

```
    $phoneErr = "";  
    $phone = "";

  if (empty($_POST["phone"])) {
     $phone = "";
   } else if(!preg_match( $phone, '/^(?:\(\+?44\)\s?|\+?44 ?)?(?:0|\(0\))?\s?(?:(?:1\d{3}|7[1-9]\d{2}|20\s?[78])\s?\d\s?\d{2}[ -]?\d{3}|2\d{2}\s?\d{3}[ -]?\d{4}) $/')) 
   {
       $phoneErr = "Invalid phone number"; 
   }else {
       $phone = test_input($_POST["phone"]);
   }
test_input($data) {
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
}
```

If it's not a number nothing will be inserted to the database, but if I typed a number **9223372036854775807** will be inserted, this value is not the one I entered.  I have done some researches, I think this value means invalid string.

Other parts of my form are working fine only the phone number not working well, I am not sure why.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8099177/validating-uk-phone-numbers-in-php

Comment: In your php code, where you define `$phone` var? Are you sure about [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) syntax? And what about the space at the end of pattern? Where is it `test_input()` function?

Comment: I have defined $phone var on top of my php code. isset button click $phone= $_post['phone'];  the preg_match I just googled it. I just updated my question for text_input function. thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: your regular expression (even purged by final space) doesn't match **9223372036854775807**.

You don't show how you insert values in database, but if above code is for checking the phone number, it's a mystery how any phone number can be inserted, unless you insert `$_POST['phone']`. But why you insert `$_POST['phone']` if you before try to convert it in `$phone`?

I say “try”, because in fact the line `$phone = test_input($_POST["phone"])` never happens.

If `$_POST['phone']` is empty, you set `$phone` to empty string (this in unnecessary: `$phone` is already an empty string, but this is not a problem), otherwise you test your regular expression, but you test it on `$phone` (an empty string), not on `$_POST['phone']`; in addition, you invert [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) arguments, so in fact you test if an empty pattern matches string `/^(?:\(\+?44\)\s?|\ ...`.

You have to rewrite your check routine in something like this:

```
$phoneErr = False;  
$phone    = "";

if( ! empty( $_POST["phone"] ) ) 
{
    $pattern = '/^(?:\(\+?44\)\s?|\+?44 ?)?(?:0|\(0\))?\s?(?:(?:1\d{3}|7[1-9]\d{2}|20\s?[78])\s?\d\s?\d{2}[ -]?\d{3}|2\d{2}\s?\d{3}[ -]?\d{4})$/';
    if( !preg_match( $pattern, $phone ) )
    {
        $phoneErr = "Invalid phone number"; 
    }
    else 
    {
        $phone = test_input($_POST["phone"]);
    }
}

(...)

if( $phoneErr )
{
    // Your error routine here
}
elseif( $phone )
{
    // Insert $phone (not $_POST['phone']) to database
}
```

Regarding your regular expression, check it with more than one UK valid numbers on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/qJ9sS8/1) before using it. As alternative, you can try the regular expressions suggested in [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8099177/validating-uk-phone-numbers-in-php) cited in comments.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**

```
<?php
 require_once('connect.php');
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $name= strip_tags($_POST['name']);  
        $phone = strip_tags($_POST['phone']);   

        if($name=="")   {
            $error[] = "Please enter name.";    
        }
        else if(!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/', $name)) 
        {
            // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
           $error[] = "Only letters and white space allowed for name"; 
        }

    else
    {
        if( !empty($phone) ) 
        {
            $pattern = '/^(?:\(\+?44\)\s?|\+?44 ?)?(?:0|\(0\))?\s?(?:(?:1\d{3}|7[1-9]\d{2}|20\s?[78])\s?\d\s?\d{2}[ -]?\d{3}|2\d{2}\s?\d{3}[ -]?\d{4})$/';
            if(!preg_match($pattern, $phone)){
                $error[] = 'Please enter a valid phone number!';
            }else{


         try {
             $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
             $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);     

             $stmt =$conn->prepare( "INSERT INTO contact (name,phone)
                  VALUES( :name, :phone)");

              $stmt->bindparam(':name', $name); 
              $stmt->bindparam(':phone', $phone);   
              $stmt->execute(); 

            }catch(PDOException $e) {
             echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
             die();
            }

            }
        }
        }
}
?>
```