# !preg_match - non US phone numbers

Tags: php, preg-match

in the past I have only been required to use a preg_match for US only numbers such as:

```
elseif(!preg_match("/^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/", $telefon))
    {
        $error = "Your message has not been sent as you did not enter your telephone number, please try again.";
        selected_values();
    }
```

But I not need to expand to incorporate UK and German number.

These numbers are often formatted with [spaces] and (brackets).

I tried the following with litte success:

```
elseif(!preg_match("/^[0-9]$/", $telefon))
```

Can anyone help me to have a preg_match that incorporates many different variations of phone numbers?

THANKS

Comment: Strip the input of everything but numeric characters and the plus sign. Then validate the length for each country. You don't even need regular expressions for this.

Comment: I personally I hate when someone tells me how I should enter my number. If someone does not want to provide you valid number, he won't. No matter how cool validation you'll make. If you require a phone number, I would just limit vaidation to say it cannot be empty. You can set min length, but again, if someone does not want to provide it, he won't.

Comment: @mkk now you say it, YES, i totally agree!!

Comment: And then you hope your country doesn't have variable length codes, or that people will leave off the +, or that the rules will change.

Answer (score 0):

For UK numbers, there's a pretty good answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32401/validate-a-uk-phone-number). (not the accepted answer tho! as the comment says, that's not a good answer)

But if you're trying to accept international numbers in general, you need to be pretty open about what you accept -- In addition to brackets and spaces, you may also find people using plus signs, dots, hyphens, slashes, and more.

There is a recognised standard for international phone number formatting, which looks like this:

```
+44.1234567890
```

Where `+44` is the international dialcode (UK in this case), followed by a dot, followed by the rest of the number (minus the leading zero, where applicable) without any other formatting.

Of course that doesn't help if you need to accept numbers being entered by users with whatever formatting they're using, but it might help if you consider this format as a target -- ie, accept whatever the user enters, and try to reformat it to this standard.

Once you've decided to do that, the process becomes simply a case of stripping off any formatting from the main number. You don't really need to worry about what formatting is supplied as long as the number of digits is correct. Then just prepend the country code and the dot, and you're done.