# php remove all 0's from start of string - could be an unknown amount

Tags: php

I have a telephone verification system in place. This allows the customer to enter a phone number. However, how can I remove all `0`'s from the start of the string?

For example I could use `substr` to remove one or two `0`'s but what if the customer enters ten or twelve of them?

i.e The customer could enter one of the following numbers:

- 077223704750
- 0077223704750
- 00000077223704750
- 0000000000077223704750`

How can I remove all `0`'s from the start only, not from the rest of the string?

Comment: what have you tried so far please .. explain what is not working and were you got stuck

Comment: why not limit  range ....why are you taking value more then limit  and why not validation ?

Comment: if it's a telephone number and the user enters ten zeros at the front, then it's not a valid phone number, so you should reject it rather than trying to fix it.

Comment: If you want to validate UK phone numbers (you hinted they're UK in one of the comments), you might be interested in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32401/validate-a-uk-phone-number/7728183#7728183

Answer (score 15):

Use [`ltrim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php)

```
$string = ltrim($string, '0');
```

[**Working DEMO**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/dmBKCZ)

Answer (score 8):

Really?  Leading 0s are dialling prefixes -- if you take them off, the phone number is not the same & may (likely) be undiallable. You make also encounter plus '+' which is an international dialling prefix, and is (meant to be) standard from location to location.

If you really want to remove leading '0's,  then use ltrim.

```
$trimmed = ltrim( $phone, '0');
```

Comment: Also note, that leading `+` in the international phone numbers has an official alias that is `00`

Comment: I'll be handling all the prefixes, in a seperate part of the code, just want to remove the 0 as this will likely need to be replaced with +44

Comment: Really, if the user enters too many zeros, and you KNOW all the prefixes, just give him an error because "0-00.." or "00-00..." is no valid phone number. Do not try to remove something that is an error, do not try to repair it without the users consent and feedback.

Comment: You're assuming far too much.  Unless you **really really** know what you're doing, don't bungle the data -- correct values can never be recovered. Only amateurs do irreversible data-loss like this.

Answer (score 4):

Use [**ltrim**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php) function.

```
$number=  ltrim($number,'0');
```

**[DEMO.](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Utx6tO)**

Comment: That won't trim the `0`s off the beginning of the string - you need to assign the result of `ltrim()` back to `$number`

Answer (score 4):

also you can use regexp

```
$result = preg_replace('/^0*/', '', $number);
```